# Google Chrome does not tile in Awesome WM

Tags: google-chrome, debian, awesome-wm

I cannot make Google Chrome tile correctly in Awesome WM (version 4.3 in Debian 10 & 11). Chrome's window stops responding, or goes blank, if it is resized (a new tile is added next to it, or a tile is closed/minimized), or when it's open in floating mode.

This weird behavior started with the recent version of Chrome (probably, 86). Only Chrome is affected, Firefox and all other applications I use work without problems.

I tried running Chrome with debug log, but there is nothing helpful there. No error messages appear, neither in `journalctl` nor in `~/.xsession-errors`.

Did anyone experience anything like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved after disabling "hardware acceleration" in Chrome. Seems like this feature didn't work well on my system (intel hd graphics 4400 and Awesome WM).